# Node.js readline in a synchronized way? Or an asynchronous loop?

Tags: node.js, readline, synchronous

I'm teaching programming to a kid using javascript / node.js and we were going to make a number guessing game. But I found that `readline` module only supports async, this means that the game logic can't be:

```
while(true){
   guess=input(); // I seem to need block here
   ans=checkGuess(guess);
   displayAns(ans);
   if(ans==0)break;
}
```

Instead, I see that instead of a simple loop, I will need to call `input` in `displayAns` which is called by `checkGuess`, which is called by `input` - and that is definitely a ugly mess. I don't think I should be teaching the kid CPS just to solve this easy problem.

Is there a simple and easy way for a kid to make this game in node.js? Or am I using the wrong language (maybe BASIC instead?)

Comment: you can use d8 shell instead node.js for this type of problems

Comment: Python is probably a better choice as a first language.  The async nature of node.js makes it difficult to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Try node.js commander.

```
$ npm install commander
```

github: https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in javascripter's answer he said to use node `commander`. node commander has no input functions any more );

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`question` method](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_callback) it pauses the input stream which, for your purpose, would be the same as "synchronous"